# NetSuite authorize username password from RESTlet

Tags: netsuite, basic-authentication, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to validate a username and password from an external website that connects to NetSuite via a RESTlet, I have to do this to satisfy the 2020.2 restrictions on the older username/password authentication which is being removed completely. Does anyone have any idea how this is done, I have looked in the docs and have not seen anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you authenticating with C# or JS?

Comment: @zerecees Thanks, Javascript, I am authenticating in the RESTlet.  I have to use OAuth to connect but then I have to authenticate the username/password after the connection is made. I would think that NetSuite would leave some way of still using external logins, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TBA(Token Based Authentication)](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4247329078.html) to authenticate your RESTlet requests in NetSuite, and recently NetSuite has added support for OAuth2.

I haven't used OAtuh2 in NetSuite, but to implement OAuth1, you need to do the following.

1. Create [Integration Record](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=bridgehead_4249032125.html).
2. Create [Tokens](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=bridgehead_4249078810.html) for TBA
3. Request RESTlet using those tokens.

You check [this](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4247337262.html) out for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I am already using TBA I need to also authenticate a username password for login. They are removing NLAuth which I used previously that used a username password, now I need to validate the user post connection with a username password challenge and also to know what data to provide for the user

Comment: are you using NLAuth header? Take a look at vendor/customer center roles/logins and you can *SuiteTalk* to access NetSuite.

Comment: they are removing NLAuth that is why I am looking for alternatives to the username password challenge scenario

Comment: Ok, so you can take a look at vendor/customer center roles for authentication.